# Issues with PHP INSERT form

Tags: php, html, wordpress

So I'm trying to get this php code to display a textarea and submit button so a user can submit a bio that gets inserted into a db. I have a few issues with this code:

1. For some reason, the text area is filled with the actual form HTML instead of just a blank box, so it shows as:

   ```html
   <form action='page-bio.php' method='post'>
       <textarea name='author_bio' value=<input type='hidden' name='hidden' value=
       <input type='submit' name='update' value=update
   </form>.
   ```
2. I'm using wordpress, so this is a php template, but I am wondering if this code will properly get the current user and insert the user's bio into the user's bio field in the database? I have a feeling it won't, but I can't tell because I still can't get the submit button to display.

```php
<?php
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","XXXX","XXXX");
    if (!$con){
        die("can not connect: " . mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_select_db("i5412",$con);

    // Get the current user's info 
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();


    if(isset($_POST['update'])){ 
        $UpdateQuery = "UPDATE wp_usermeta SET author_bio='".$_POST['author_bio']."'WHERE
        user_id=$current_user and author_bio='".$_POST['hidden']."'";
        mysql_query($UpdateQuery, $con);
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM wp_usermeta";
    $myData = mysql_query($sql,$con);
    while($record = mysql_fetch_array($myData)){
        echo "<form action='page-bio.php' method='post'>";
        echo "<textarea name='author_bio' cols='10' rows='10' value=" . $record['author_bio'];
        echo "<input type='hidden' name='hidden' value=" . $record['author_bio'];
        echo "<input type='submit' name='update' value=update";
        echo "</form>";
    }
    mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: You forgot to close almost all the form element tags.

Comment: `echo "<textarea name='author_bio' cols='10' rows='10' value=" . $record['author_bio'];` should be `echo "<textarea name='author_bio' cols='10' rows='10'>" . $record['author_bio'] . "</textarea>";`

Comment: `echo "<input type='hidden' name='hidden' value=" . $record['author_bio'];` should be `echo "<input type='hidden' name='hidden' value='" . $record['author_bio'] ."' >";`

Comment: `echo "<input type='submit' name='update' value=update";` should be `echo "<input type='submit' name='update' value='update'>";`

Comment: @ThinkDifferent Please delete your comments now that you've sent an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the following lines:

```
echo "<textarea name='author_bio' cols='10' rows='10' value=" . $record['author_bio'];
echo "<input type='hidden' name='hidden' value=" . $record['author_bio'];
echo "<input type='submit' name='update' value=update";
```

To

```
echo "<textarea name='author_bio' cols='10' rows='10'>" . $record['author_bio'] . "</textarea>";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='hidden' value='" . $record['author_bio']. "'>";
echo "<input type='submit' name='update' value='update'>" ;
```

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to close half of the input tags such as `echo "<input type='submit' name='update' value=update";` where you missed the ending >

Comment: I don't know who downvoted your question but this is most certainly the cause, but please add some code sample.

Comment: If I add the whole code, wouldn't he just copy+paste it and not learn anything as opposed to getting him in the right direction and letting him solve it and therefore learning something?

Comment: I appreciate you comment Limiter, but I've been spending countless hours trying to learn which I want to do. And there is a lot ahead of me and sometimes I just need to get something to work so I don't lose heart. This code almost works but now issue 2 I mentioned is as I feared: this is a wordpress template called from a WP page and it does not accept $current_user = wp_get_current_user(); That is, when i leave wordpress for this php page, it does not keep the current user variable i suppose, so this might be another dead end for using php insert with wordpress :(

Comment: @Limiter I know exactly what you mean, but you know, there are people who don't read properly and just downvote because of "too short", "doesn't provide sample", etc.